# Image in menu box with submenu object

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a css menu and want all the ones that have submenus have a little > image at the side of the box.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/u9KrH/4/
There are also two JS files that go with it, but i can't attach those to that editor, but you can see it in action here: http://trulyscience.com/test/index.php

I hoped that changing `ul.dropdown li:last-child a` would do the job, but that didn't fix it at all. So now I am clueless, does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On that trulyscience.com page, you just need to tweak the background property for `ul.dropdown li:last-child a`.

CSS defaults to tiling backgrounds, so you need to replace

```
background-image: url('images/redarrow.jpg');
```

with

```
background: url('images/redarrow.jpg') no-repeat right center;
```

Which positions the background and stops it repeating. You can also use px or % values in place of 'right' and 'center'.

A more verbose version of the same code is:

```
background-image: url('images/redarrow.jpg');
background-position: right center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

The result is:

[image: repeating CSS background]

Becomes:

[image: Positioned CSS background]

Comment: Hmm it doesn't quite work as I wanted, I hoped that it only picked the ones that had submenus, but it just picks the last one.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Try adding an `:only-child` selector with `background:none`. Once you've done this, you could change `li:last-child a` to just `li a`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/u9KrH/5/)
But it seems to ignore the tag and give them all a arrow.

Comment: That's targeting the li when the background is on the a. Try `ul.dropdown li:only-child a`. **Edit**: Oops, wrong way around - I meant `ul.dropdown li a:only-child`. There's a really comprehensive list of selectors here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: We think alike. :P No change though. **Edit:** It works! Also thanks for the list, I couldn't find one anywhere (apart from w3schools, which isn't good/complete)

Comment: Awesome. If you wanted to invert it so browsers that don't support `:only-child` don't show the arrows on all the items, you could remove the background property from `ul.dropdown li a` and put it in a selector `ul.dropdown li a:not(:only-child)`

Comment: Oh, yes I forgot about that! I also remove `ul.dropdown li a:only-child  {background:none}`?